# Split large collection of marked tests to run in parallel - pytest

Tags: pytest, selenium-grid

I have a very large collection of tests that I am invoking using the mark method as follows

```
pytest -s -v -m smoketest
```

I am running tests on a selenium grid so I need to be able to run this collection in parallel. Since this invocation only sends one request to the grid the tests run sequentially. How to achieve parallelism here? Thanks for your help

Comment: have you looked at `pytest-parallel`? -- https://github.com/browsertron/pytest-parallel

Comment: @TeejayBruno I did. It seems to be crashing python for me on Python 3.10. Also the project is not maintained. Only pytest-xdist works

Comment: Have you seen this https://pytest-xdist.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the pytest plugin pytest-test-groups I was able to break a large collection of tests into groups and run that group. I believe this is the best solution for a CI setup

Example below

## Split the tests into 10 groups and run the second group

py.test --test-group-count 10 --test-group=2